# Exposing a class through another class with consistent naming in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

In the pseudo code below, if I have two classes and I want one class to be initialized in the other class without the name having to be different, how would I accomplish this?

```
'==Car.vb==
Public Class Car
    Public Model as New Car.Model()
End Class

'==Model.vb==
Partial Class Car
    Public Class Model
        Public Enum Types
            BMW
            Audi
            Yugo
        End Enum
        'Do Something
    End Class
End Class

'==ASPX page==
Dim c as New Car()
c.Model = Car.Model.Types.BMW
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the New Model object is named the same thing as the Car.Model class.  I just don't want to have to create a "Model" object also every time I define a car class but I also don't want the names to be all stupid like this:

```
'==Car.vb==
Public Class Car
    Public Model as New Car.CarModel()
End Class

'==Model.vb==
Partial Class Car
    Public Class CarModel
        Public Enum Types
            BMW
            Audi
            Yugo
        End Enum
        'Do Something
    End Class
End Class

'==ASPX page==
Dim c as New Car()
c.Model = Car.CarModel.Types.BMW
```

Is there a better way of doing this so I get the result I want for my usage code?

```
'==ASPX page==
Dim c as New Car()
c.Model = Car.Model.Types.BMW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, and is in general a bad idea.

[You should avoid exposing nested types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx).

Comment: So how would you do this instead so that the final usage code doesn't change?

Comment: @SLaks - thanks for your time on this.  What would be the standard practice for doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @EdenMachine: Standard practice would be to use a non-nested enum called `CarModels` or `CarTypes`.